# Forwarding Traffic From One Port to Another and Vice Versa

Tags: networking, iptables, port-forwarding, tcp-ip

The goal: Have process A send messages to process B and vice versa via TCP (I'm using ROSBridge).

The problem: Only one process can use a port at a time

The solution (?): Have process A use port 9090 but forward the traffic to 9091 and have process B use port 9091 but forward the traffic to port 9090.

The question: Will this solution work or would I get an infinite loop of repeating data? Any way not to do that? If this would work, how do I set it up? If it will not work, what else can I do?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "forward" in this case, since traffic originating at 9090 is *sent* (not forwarded) to 9091. If you have traffic from process X on port 8500 that must be sent to both A and B, send one message to each independently, no forwarding. TCP is a unicast (not multicast) protocol.

Comment: Generally, interprocess communication in Ubuntu is handled by dbus, which is already installed, and has lots useful features, and lots of bindings available. Look it up. Feel free to use it, that's what it is there for, You can implement your own, of course, using pipes, named pipes, sockets, shared files, and other methods, if you wish - use of dbus is merely convenient, not required.

Comment: It's possible (and perhaps likely) that I just don't understand ports. When I launch my ROSBridge node, I tell it to use port 9090 for sending/receiving data. My other process, Unity, needs to send and receive data from ROSBridge so I need to also tell it to use port 9090 where the data is. If I tell it to use a different port, it will not see the ROSBridge Data. Unfortunately, it seems that two processes can't use the same port. That, or I'm getting some other problem that I'm not aware of. It works fine, however, if my Unity app is on a different PC. I know nothing of unicast or multicast.

Comment: As for dbus, I'm utilizing pre-made packages where you simply select the port to use. It seems I may have to modify them though to get what I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like my understanding about ports was lacking. The host for the ROSBridge is being set up to use port 9090 so that anyone wishing to connect to it will request the host's port 9090 for the connection but will still use whatever port it desires on its own side. In both applications, I can state that the "Host" port is 9090 without conflict because the client application will still open a random other port for its own use to connect to the host port. Therefore, the trouble I am experiencing is something other than "port sharing" since that is not what is happening. Only one is hosting on 9090.